# Boot Ubuntu, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10 Technical Preview with Grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, bootloader

I originally installed Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu, using grub to give me a selection of operating systems to boot to when it starts up, and that works fine. I decided I wanted to try the Windows 10 Technical Preview, so I installed that, which messed things up with Grub, but after a while I fixed that, so now Grub again selects my OS. Unfortunately, it only shows Ubuntu and Windows 8, not Windows 10. Once I select Windows 8, it uses Windows 8's boot loader. I would much rather have Grub give me the options to select Ubuntu, Windows 8, and Windows 10, and get rid of the second level boot loader. Does anyone know how I could go about doing that?

Comment: Are all systems installed in BIOS boot mode or UEFI boot mode? IF BIOS are both Windows installed in BIOS boot mode on primary partitions? Windows will not directly boot from a logical. It can only boot thru a primary partition.